# Read data from environment odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm try read all name from res.partner but always console return empty res.partner()

In database I have record where is company_id = 1

```py
@api.multi   
def test(self):
    my_ids = self.env['res.partner'].search([('company_id','=','1')])
    print(my_ids)
```

Comment: Did you try `[('company_id','=',1)]`  instead of [('company_id','=','1')] ?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas   Thanks a lot of....